# Multi Criteria Evaluation implemented via a website

Tags: web-mapping, suitability-analysis, multi-criteria-analysis

I'm wondering if there are any websites where spatial multi-criteria evaluation can be performed by a user selecting criteria from their web browser and the result being presented as an online map.

TerrSet does MCE very well, but I would like to have some web application that can replicate what TerrSet does, and present the result as an online map. Ideally, I'd like to provide a range of spatial data sets that a web user can select from, then rank in importance, then perform MCE, which will then return spatial features ranked by suitability according to the ranked multiple criteria that the user selected. Any examples of this online?